# UIButton Placement and Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I'm trying to make the position of my buttons according to screen sizes by doing this

```
storeButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width / 5, y: self.frame.height / 1.43, width: self.frame.width / 10, height: self.frame.height / 12)
```

but, what happens is it goes according to the current size I run it on and when I switch to lets say a iPhone 5 its not quite were I want it.

Comment: use constraints ..

Comment: I don't know how to use constraints programtically @KishoreKumar

Comment: Where are you trying to place it in plain English?  Does it need to have a specific size or a proportional size?  Does it need a specific position or a proportional position?  Also, check out [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout).

Comment: I'm trying to place different buttons in different places, but i want them to be proportional on all screen sizes @nhgrif

Comment: @JulianCearley If you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36102833/edit) to include all the relevant details about where it should be placed in the various different screen sizes, someone could help you figure out what sort of constraints to add.

Comment: Also check out Masonry (obj-c) and its Swift alt SnapKit - both on github. Makes programmatically working with constraints a breeze.

Comment: @JulianCearley you can also try the [KVConstraintExtensionsMaster](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster) to apply the constraints programmatically

Answer (score -1):

You could use constraints.

When you want to create them programatically I would suggest the Apple Tutorial https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1

Comment: Rather than providing a link to documentation, best provide a simple code example and an explanation of how it works.